# How to restart a command if it hasn't updated a file for a few minutes

Tags: shell-script, watchdog

I'm kinda new to bash scripting so bear with me.

I have a program that prints logs almost every second into a file. I want it to restart if current time is few mins more than the file's last modification time.

Answer (score 0):

You can try this by matching the time series you want to appear in the logs with the `grep` command, and then confirming whether to restart the service based on the return value

Then configure this script to the job schedule `crond` or `systemd.timer`

```bash
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/ansible/k8s-pod-create]
└─$grep Pod demo.yaml
kind: Pod
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/ansible/k8s-pod-create]
└─$echo $?
0
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/ansible/k8s-pod-create]
└─$grep pod demo.yaml
┌──[root@vms81.liruilongs.github.io]-[~/ansible/k8s-pod-create]
└─$echo $?
1
```

This is a `python` implementation of the demo, can be used as a reference, here there is no restart service, but an alert SMS occurred

```py
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-
"""
@File    :   ipcc_log_mis.py
@Time    :   2022/10/13 17:27:15
@Author  :   Li Ruilong
@Version :   1.0
@Contact :   1224965096@qq.com
@Desc    :   IPCC日志监控
             如果日志文件不存在，或者当天的日志没有，会发送告警短信
"""

# here put the import lib


import subprocess

parser = argparse.ArgumentParser(description='简单的日志监控：如果命令失败或者不是成功状态码，执行对应的操作')



try:
    com = 'tail -n 10 /home/****/RecordUser.log | grep -i $(date +%m-%d)'
    out_bytes = subprocess.check_output(com, shell=True)
    out_bytes = out_bytes.decode('utf-8')
    # print out_bytes
except subprocess.CalledProcessError as e:
    out_bytes = e.output  # Output generated before error
    line = 'mysql -h 192.168.50.187 -P 3306 -u PT90  *************   --database cloud -A  -e"{sql}" > /dev/null 2>&1'
    sql = "insert into nm_sms_send (accNbr,smsContent,spId) values ('181****5370','【XX平台】IPCC 日志异常，监控不到当天日志。请排查，$(date)',1);"
    sql += "insert into nm_sms_send (accNbr,smsContent,spId) values ('153****7834','【XX平台】IPCC 日志异常，监控不到当天日志。请排查，$(date)',1);"
    line = line.format(sql=sql)
    subprocess.check_output(line, shell=True)
```